# There is an error in fetching and checkout from the remote to local from the bitbucket?

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket

**Error**

```
remote: Counting objects: 182, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (149/149), done..
error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

I Could not find what is the actual problem as I had setup everything. I tried to fetch and checkout to another branch from remote but only master branch is shown and could not checkout and error shown above.

Thanks!

Comment: Please check in the git repo `.git` folder, if there has the file `.git/index-pack`. If the file `index-pack` exist, delete it and try again.